# GraphQL filter by multiple values on nested object

Tags: graphql, hotchocolate

I have a GraphQL API and want to filter the results based on the nested tag object. The object looks like this:

```json
{
    name
    ...
    tags [
        {
            name
        },
        {
            name
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I now want to get all documents that have both tags, a tag with the name "invoice" AND a tag with the name "open". How would I do that?

I already tried doing it like this:

```
query {
  documents (
    where: { tags: { some: { name: { and: { in: [ "invoice", "open" ] } } } } }
  ) {
    nodes {
      name
      tags {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and some other stuff, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you will implement that on the Backend, because the GraphQL is only a descriptive way to do "Queries and Mutations"